# java synchronized bank account transfer

Tags: java, synchronization

I tried to write synchronized code for the classic problem of BankAccount transfer. Now I am trying to figure out the problem with the solution. In any solution that I found on the web the transfer method used two locks but I did not use any.

```
    class BankAccount
    {
      double balance;

      public void synchronized deposit(double amount)
      {
          balance+=amount;
       }

      public void synchronized withdraw(double amount)
      {
         balance-=amount;
      }

      public void transferTo(BankAccount b, double amount)
      {
           this.withdraw(amount);
           b.deposit(amount);

       }
   }
```

Please tell me what could be the problem with `transferTo()`. Please excuse leaving out the limit checking on `balance`. I am actually concerned about whether not making the transferTo atomic would cause problems (deadlocks). An example of such a situation would be great.

Comment: Well one bug is the word `double` in there.

Comment: Why could be the problem with double?

Comment: If you don't round the result you can get a rounding error which some people find unacceptable. Using a `long` cents or `BigDecimal` is a good alternative. I find that rounding the result is all you need in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the use of double, I don't see any particular problems, though you have to keep in mind that transferTo not being atomic may cause issues later. However, you are in fact using locks. Each synchronized method implicitly uses a lock.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [intrinsic lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are using locks as soon as you put `synchronized` block in place. In this case the lock will be acquired over the class object which is under modification and this is the reason your code would be working fine.

But your `transferTo` method might not work correctly as both operations inside this are synchronized but not the whole transaction.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I am actually trying to find out a case in which not making the transferTo method atomic would cause problem.

Comment: @user Conceptually, it isn't a problem because in reallife, such transactions are not atomic. It's only a problem if your users expect it to be atomic. Also, it's actually locking the instance, not the class object (I think Bharat misspoke)